# Querying count of TCP Connections for a given process in Powershell

Tags: powershell, wmi-query

It seems the class to do this is [MSFT_NetTransportConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh872454(v=vs.85).aspx).

However I cannot query this class via Get-WmiObject:

```
C:\Users\Justin Dearing> Get-WmiObject MSFT_NetTransportConnection
Get-WmiObject : Invalid class "MSFT_NetTransportConnection"
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-WmiObject MSFT_NetTransportConnection
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand

C:\Users\Justin Dearing> Get-WmiObject MSFT_NetTransportConnection  -Namespace "root/StandardCimv2"
Get-WmiObject : Not supported
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-WmiObject MSFT_NetTransportConnection  -Namespace "root/StandardC ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand

C:\Users\Justin Dearing> Get-WmiObject MSFT_NetTransportConnection  -Namespace "fff"
Get-WmiObject : Invalid namespace "fff"
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-WmiObject MSFT_NetTransportConnection  -Namespace "fff"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can the [`MSFT_NetTcpConnection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh872450(v=vs.85).aspx) class be suitable?

```
Get-WmiObject -Namespace 'ROOT/StandardCimv2' -ClassName MSFT_NetTCPConnection |
    Group-Object OwningProcess
```

#### Sort Process with Most Connections

You can also use `Sort-Object` to sort the list of processes with the most connections. This makes it easier to visually discover which processes have the most connections.

```
Get-CimInstance -Namespace root/standardcimv2 -ClassName MSFT_NetTCPConnection | 
  Group-Object -Property OwningProcess | 
  Sort-Object -Property Count
```

Answer (score 3):

I also don't have that WMI/CIM class. You may need to figure out what namespace it is in to use it.

You can get the number of network connections that each process has by using `Get-NetTCPConnection` and grouping on the `OwningProcess` property.

```
Get-NetTCPConnection -State Established, TimeWait -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
    Group-Object OwningProcess
```

Comment: That is  cool, but I want to combine with other performance counters via a WQL query so I'll go with Andrei's answer. Also, look at the two ways I run the command and the two different answers. It seems to me I did find the correct name space.